# Is it possible to write a Python class with hidden method which would only be callable if a specific attribute is set?

Tags: python

I've created a sort of encoder class that takes text data and converts them to integers and back.

However, this information is business sensitive so I don't want the decoder or encoder mapping of the class to be callable unless a specific token is typed in

for example I would want something like the code below. But since all the attributes and methods of a class are public (to my knowledge) I have no idea how to deal with it. Is it even possible?

```
import pickle

class EncoderDecoder:
    # something happens here

# dump the class
# load the class
ed = EncoderDecoder(*args, **kwargs)
ed.encode(sentence) # raises some error
ed.decode(sentence) # raises some error
ed.set_token = "pasword1234"
ed.encode(sentence) # returns encoded
ed.decode(sentence) # returns decoded

# the user can't access set_token property setter or decoder method
```

Comment: if you want to hide information you need to keep non trusted users outside of your process. There is no programming technique that can help you if the user has permission to read the memory address space of the process holding sensitive data.

Comment: Access modifiers are to hide implementation, not secrets :), and anyway python doesn't have any access modifiers.

Comment: I second what @geckos says.  You could use introspection to hack on the definition of the class or object and probably figure out how to do what you're asking.  But then so could the caller of your code. Again, once someone is allowed to run code in a Python interpreter that has access to sensitive data, that person can find a way to get at that data no matter what you do to hide methods, or anything else.

Comment: ...to answer your question more specifically though...why not just have the method fail if the token has not been provided first? - in fact...I just noticed that this is what you show in your sample code.  So what's wrong with that?  I assume you know how to check for the token and return an error or throw an exception if one has not been set.

Comment: If you're talking about the set_token method being available...why does that matter?  It should be the specific value of the token that matters.  If the caller knows about that attribute and sets it to some value but not **the correct value**, then the code should just fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution exploiting how Python handles class members.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.method = None

    def enable_method():
        def method():
            # do thing
            pass

        self.method = method
```

That should do the trick for you.  Because the actual method definition only exists in the context of `enable_method`, it is not accessible externally.  Since Python is not type-safe, you can change `self.method` to a function type from a none type without any problems.

Hope this helps!